# Meteor reactive issue between minomongo and publisher

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-react

I am working on sort option in list of documents. same sort query has both publisher and client side. If two or more document has same sort value. I can see the juggling when I update lot. the below code will explain you very clearly.

```
Meteor.publish('Products', function(options) {
    return Products.find({},sort:{price:-1})
});

Template.name.onCreated(function() {
    Template.instance().subscribe('Products');
});

Template.name.helpers({
    products: function(){
        return Products.find({},sort:{price:-1})
    }
});

Template.name.events({
    'click #productid': fucntion(){
        //update product document (not the price field).
    }
});
```

Some products has same price. I clicked on the top product which is same price. after update the document by click event.The clicked product comes to the end of the same price document. How to solve this issue?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand correctly. To resolve ties you can use the `_id` as the second sort parameter. For example:
`{ sort: {price: -1, _id: 1} }`

Also, using `sort` in your publication won't change anything in this specific example. You can remove it if you want. `sort` in the publication will make a difference if you use `limit` in your query.

Comment: You understand my question correctly and THANKS a lot Eliezer Steinbock, It works fine. I am using `limit` in publication so that's why doing sort on both side.